# How do you use the gradient to find $n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$

$$W = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$$$$\overrightarrow{N} = \nabla W   = \langle 2x,2y,2z \rangle$$

$$\overrightarrow{n} = \frac{\overrightarrow{N}}  {\|\overrightarrow{N}\|} = \frac{\langle x,y,z \rangle}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = \langle x,y,z \rangle$$

My question is how did it come out to be ? And shouldn't you be plugging in $\langle 2x,2y,2z \rangle$ in the denominator for $x,y,z$ inside the sqrt, so shouldn't it be $\sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2}$? And then shouldn't it equal $$\left \langle \frac{x}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2}} \right \rangle $$ and not just $\langle x,y,z \rangle$
?

The original question was evaluate integral of C of 
$$$$$$\overrightarrow{F} *d \overrightarrow{r} $$ where $$$$$$\overrightarrow{F}(x,y,z) = <e^(-x^2)+sinx, e^(-y^2)-2yz, x^2+ e^(-z^2)=2z> $$ and C is the boundary of the surface $$z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$ oriented Counterclockwise.

Comment: You are correct. Both of the as serrations you make are true. However, upon simplification, you get the result that you have given.

Answer (score 1):

You should only "plug in $\langle 2x,2y,2z\rangle$ in the denominator" if you also use them in the numerator. Then you get $$\overrightarrow{n} = \frac{\overrightarrow{N}}  {\|\overrightarrow{N}\|} = \frac{\langle 2x,2y,2z \rangle}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 + (2y)^2 + (2z)^2}} = \frac{2\langle x,y,z \rangle}{2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$$ and a simple cancellation.

Comment: but how does sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) in the denominator become 1 all of a sudden and you are left with <x,y,z>?

Comment: @Walter, what is your definition of $z$? Given that, what can you conclude about $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$?

Comment: $$z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$ oh so does $$sqrt(1 - x^2 - y^2)$$ always represent the radius?

Comment: @Walter, whenever $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ it represents *a* radius, but that's not a helpful way of thinking about it in general. *In this particular case*, your surface $C$ is a hemisphere of radius 1.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to note what you mean by$\overrightarrow{n}$.
Assuming that you meant the direction orthogonal to $W$, then your claim sounds valid.
The norm of $\overrightarrow{N}$ is not always 1, so it shouldn't simplify like that all the time.
The only case where $\overrightarrow{N} \over ||\overrightarrow{N}||$ equals $\overrightarrow{N}$ itself is only when $\overrightarrow{N}$ itself is a unit vector, as in $\sqrt{(2x)^2+(2y)^2+(2z)^2}=1$

My suggestion is, write down the exact problem that you are working on so that everyone can see better what you are really trying to do.

Comment: $\vec{v}$ is an alternate notation for a vector

Comment: @hyg17 what do you mean the norm of $\overrightarrow{N}$ is not always 1? Isn't $\overrightarrow{N}$ = <2x,2y,2z>? How can you tell by the question if the norm of $\overrightarrow{N}$ is 1?

Comment: @hyg17 I edited the question by the way

Comment: The norm of $\overrightarrow N$ which is $||\overrightarrow N||$ is basically the length of the vector. Since $\overrightarrow N$ has variables, you specifically need the values of $x,y \text{ and }z$ in order to find its norm. When you divide the vector $\overrightarrow N$ by its norm, the length becomes 1. It's called a direction vector.